# How to start cron jobs removing offset?

Tags: linux, cron

I am running a cron job which will run at every 5 minutes.

Now Let's say i have started job on 04:02 so it will execute at every 5 minutes so will execute on 04:07, 04:12, 04:17 etc...

Let's say i have started job on 13:18 so it will executed at 13:23, 13:28, 13:33 etc...

But what i want is it should only execute in multiplication of 5 minutes means if i create job on 04:02, it should start executing from 04:05, 04:10 and so on.

And if start job on 13:18, it should start executing from 13:20, 13:25 and so on.

So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * <Your command>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*/5 * * * *
```

this should be what you want .

Comment: This is what he is already doing. I think you did not understand the question @Ksir

Comment: @KSir Sultan is right...I want it to execute at fixed minutes in multiplication of 5 like 00:05, 00:10, 00:15 etc. I think that will work.

Comment: @RushabhShah ok. Sultan's method works well, but on my machine */5 * * * * really work the same.